# Rename file name based on upload date

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I write the below code to copy the file and rename file name but the problem that i have now that i need to pick the last file (based on upload date) then rename the file , the below code change all files placed in the folder regardless the upload date , also if there is a simple code to upload file check if file is exist then show message (successful upload , failed upload (duplicate file))

```
Dim directory = Server.MapPath("App_Data/text/")

For Each filename As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

        Dim fName As String = IO.Path.GetFileName(filename)

        If fName.ToString Like "*Cust*" Then

            System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath("App_Data\test\Customer.txt"))
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(Server.MapPath("App_Data\text\" & fName), Server.MapPath("App_Data\test\" & fName))
            My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(Server.MapPath("App_Data\test\" & fName), "Customer.txt")
```

Comment: Can you use the [creation date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getcreationtime?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: @the_lotus creation date may be difficult as some files loaded are offline ( as example the file created on 01-07-2019 and the upload date was on 04-07-2019) what i need exactly is to look at upload date , if not possible let me know how to handle this based on creation date.

Comment: I think I mixed up, I tought the files were downloaded in a server and you wanted to track the time. If your client upload the file somewhere and you want to track the time, that might be more difficult since this isn't log in the file system but might be log in the program that uploads the files.

Comment: `string.Format("{0:dd_MMM_yyyy}", DateTime.Now);` is C# change it to its equivalent in vb and save the file with it

Comment: The file will be uploaded to server after that the system will start rename process based on upload date or creation date, I only need to put condition that instruct the program to rename last file loaded on the server, also in case multiple file found with same name I need the program to merge all of them in one file, is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 1):

you can use below code and find creation date and last modified date of a file:

```
Dim creation as DateTime = File.GetCreationTime(@"C:\test.txt")
Dim modification as DateTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(@"C:\test.txt")
```

or by Importing `System.IO` and using this code:

```
Dim fi as FileInfo = new FileInfo("path")
Dim created = fi.CreationTime
Dim lastmodified = fi.LastWriteTime
```

i think the second one is better because you can put them in a collection easily and then sort them or compare them.

Comment: Thanks Ehsan for your input the code is not working fine as the file date modified to today's date after the user upload the file on the server, if there any solution for this issue please let me know, also if you have any simple code to upload file on the sever and keep the file data as is like creation date it will be better thanks in advance

Comment: you wanted to "pick the last file (based on upload date)", right? so it would work for you. you can have upload date (based on date modified) by this code.